# How Can We retrieve the BSE AND NSE stock quote symbols?

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0

IS it possible to retrieve the BSE and NSE stock quote symbols from  "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="

Comment: This seems to be old question, but cross referencing it to another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23857645/260665

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of the symbols your looking for from the free BATS exchange. Here is an example [Download Stock Symbols](http://www.jarloo.com/download-stock-symbols/)

Answer (score 0):

Append the link "http://subscribers.capitalmarket.com/getquotes/bsequots.asp?SearchText=" with the text to search for. This gives you the symbol(s) and names of companies in BSE and NSE.

NSE list
https://www.nseindia.com/content/corporate/eq_research_reports_listed.htm https://www.nseindia.com/content/corporate/eq_rrl_m2z.htm

Post if there is any.Hope this helps.