# Get stock quotes of NSE and BSE using web-service and parse it using json

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, stockquotes

I want to show all stock price of NSE and BSE on simple html page.

I got information from google that i can call any web service that is already exist and they will give all information in json form. And then I have to parse that jason code.

Now I want someone to provide me link by which i can call the webservice. And let me know how can i call that web service using jQuery. And how can i parse output json data.
If any one can give me sample code then it will be best..

Thank you so much for helping me.. :)

Comment: You want (a) a link to call the webservice, (b) information about using jQuery with that, (c) information about how to parse the json data, and (d) sample code? That's quite a tall order!

Comment: try nsepy library!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to fetch the data from NSE web service, then below is the link:

http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/ajaxGetQuoteJSON.jsp?symbol=dhfl

But I'm not sure whether you can use this link or not for non commercial as well as commercial purpose.

As the site has been updated and old site is no more working, updating answers with new updated links:

Equity link -
https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=RELIANCE
https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=RELIANCE&section=trade_info

Derivatives link:
https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=RELIANCE

**I'm not sure whether you can use this link or not for non commercial as well as commercial purpose**

Comment: 405 method not allowed! is the URL changed?

Comment: Yes website is also changed with new UI

Comment: EQ link https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=RELIANCE&section=trade_info  derivatives link https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=RELIANCE

Comment: Proper Documentation for NSE Api? Like search company. Search historical for a duration. etc?

Comment: Any endpoint for commodities? Like Gold/Silver? I tried to replace equity with commodity but it didn't work

Comment: gold silver can be found on mcx india.. nseindia does not provide commodity feed

Comment: no documentation. simply generate the classes and use it the way you want.

Comment: You can try with https://www.jimmypoint.com/questions/6134dbad36065b0017d44f46/nse-bse-api-free

Answer (score 6):

For a free service you can call google finance web services or yahoo finance web services, but both are deprecated but are still working.

http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/IDFC.NS/quote?format=json&view=detail

in above URL: 
IDFC is the symbol of security
.NS stands for NSE

For BSE just modify NS to BO

for google web service:
NSE:
http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:DHFL

for BSE just modify NSE to BOM

Just copy pate above links in a browser to see json output.

Comment: You should probably delete [your other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34471533/1364007) and include the information in this one.

Comment: I'm unable to add more than two links in one post due to reputation error. Minimum 10 reputation is required to post more than two links in an answer. I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: To be fair, this question is probably too broad anyway - I'm not sure it's worth your while answering it unless the OP edits it (unlikely since it's an old question and they've not been seen online for several months).

Comment: Yeah true, but this might help someone searching for the same...

Answer (score 3):

Please go to [this](https://github.com/ashwanthkumar/Live-NSE-Stock) GitHub library. It will surely help.

Currently it gives live stock from the official NSE site.

This services will give you a json response, you can parse this JSON to get the appropriate value, by just replacing the symbol with a valid NSE code.

Comment: library is not working !

Answer (score 2):

Google provide a free web services for NSC and BOM data.

https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NSE:KELLTONTEC&output=json

*For google web service NSE data*- https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NSE:KELLTONTEC&output=json

*For google web service BSE (BOM) data*- https://finance.google.com/finance?q=BSE:KELLTONTEC&output=json

#### In PHP

```
$bse = file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance?q=BSE:KELLTONTEC&output=json");
$split_slash= str_replace('//','',$bse );
$split_data = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($split_slash));
$data = json_decode($split_data);
$equity = $data[0]->l;
print_r($data[0]->l);
```

Its return BSE data

Comment: You have to edit your question and format as well.

Comment: Is this fine @AnandPandey

Answer (score 0):

C# code to get live updates from NSE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq; //download Newtonsoft dll from web
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Check
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //IDFCBANK

        string[] item = {"ICICIBANK","HDFCBANK"}; 

        foreach(string str in item ) 
        {
            string url = "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:" + str;
            string output = "";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            try
            {
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    output = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    write(output);
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item invalid : " + str);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static void write(string res)
    {
        try 
        {
            if (res.Length > 0)
            {
                res = res.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
                JObject rss = JObject.Parse(res);

                string Title = (string)rss["t"];
                string Time = (string)rss["ltt"];
                string Charge = (string)rss["l"];
                string Change = (string)rss["c"];
                // James Newton-King
                Console.WriteLine(Title.Substring(0,3) + " " + Time + " " + Charge + "  " + Change);


            }

        }
       catch (Exception  ex)
       {
       }
        }

    }
}
```